# Populate e-mails in outlook with the right attachments

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop, outlook

I have a function that generates Outlook e-mails and populate the e-mails with the attachments belonging to the e-mail address.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'E-mail': ['peter@gmail.com', 'peter@gmail.com', 'jake@gmail.com', 'jake@gmail.com'],
                          'Fruit': ['apple.pdf', 'pear.pdf', 'orange.pdf', 'banana.pdf']})
```

Here is my e-mail function.

```
def Email():
    for i in df['E-mail'].unique():
        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.To = i
        mail.Subject = "Fruit reports" 

        for i,j in df.groupby('E-mail')['Fruit']:
            files = j.to_frame(i)

            for fil in files[i]:
                attachment = dirLoc + '\\' + fil
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

        mail.Display(False)

Email()
```

I have issues with my for-loop. It attaches all attachments from `Fruit` rather than `apple.pdf` and `pear.pdf` to `peter@gmail.com` and `orange.pdf` and `banana.pdf` to `jake@gmail.com`.

Is there an easy solution to allocate the right attachment to the right e-mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's because you iterate over all mails again in `for i, j in df.groupby('E-mail')['Fruit']` and you actually overwrite `i`.

Perhaps a cleaner way would be to group only once, e.g. like this:

```
import os

...

def send_all_mail(df):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

    for dest_mail, group in df.groupby('E-Mail'):
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.To = dest_mail
        mail.Subject = "Fruit reports"

       for fname in group['Fruits'].unique():
           attachment = os.path.join(dirLoc, fname)
           mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
       mail.Display(False)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I am looking for.